# Access module from Vuex Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have the following module:

```
export const ProfileData = {
    state: {
        ajaxData: null;
    },
    getters: {/*getters here*/},
    mutations: {/*mutations here*/},
    actions: {/*actions here*/}
}
```

and this module is registered in my global store:

```
import {ProfileData} from './store/modules/ProfileData.es6'
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
       ProfileData: ProfileData
    }
});
```

I have also used the `Vue.use(Vuex)` and set the store in `new Vue({ store: store})` properly. However, when I try to access the `ajaxData` belonging to the `ProfileData` module, in one of my components via `this.$store.ProfileData.ajaxData`, the console shows an `undefined` error. The same goes for reading the `this.$store.ProfileData` or `this.$store.ajaxData`, while `this.$store` is defined and I am already able to read it. I also see the `ProfileData` object added to the `_modules` property of the store in browser's console.

What is that I am doing wrong to access the modules registered to the `Vuex`? How can I access those?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Directly accessing state of Vuex module

The format to access a [**Module's local state**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#module-local-state) is `$store.state.moduleName.propertyFromState`.

So you would use:

```
this.$store.state.ProfileData.ajaxData
```

Demo:

```js
const ProfileData = {
  state: {ajaxData: "foo"}
}
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  modules: {
    ProfileData
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
   console.log(this.$store.state.ProfileData.ajaxData)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>ajaxData: {{ $store.state.ProfileData.ajaxData }}</p>
</div>
```

---

## Getters, Actions and Mutators of modules, how to directly access them?

It depends if they are namespaced or not. See demo (explanation in comments):

```js
const ProfileDataWithoutNamespace = {
  state: {ajaxData1: "foo1"},
  getters: {getterFromProfileDataWithoutNamespace: (state) => state.ajaxData1}
}
const ProfileDataWithNamespace = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {ajaxData2: "foo2"},
  getters: {getterFromProfileDataWithNamespace: (state) => state.ajaxData2}
}
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  modules: {
    ProfileDataWithoutNamespace,
    ProfileDataWithNamespace
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    // state is always per module
   console.log(this.$store.state.ProfileDataWithoutNamespace.ajaxData1)
    console.log(this.$store.state.ProfileDataWithNamespace.ajaxData2)
    // getters, actions and mutations depends if namespace is true or not
    // if namespace is absent or false, they are added with their original name
    console.log(this.$store.getters['getterFromProfileDataWithoutNamespace'])
    // if namespace is true, they are added with Namespace/ prefix
    console.log(this.$store.getters['ProfileDataWithNamespace/getterFromProfileDataWithNamespace'])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Check the console.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the point here and through the `state` property I am able to get the `ajaxData` now. But, how about accessing the getters, mutations, etc). An example would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I have added another demo showing how `getters` (and actions, mutations) behave. Actually, they depend if the modules are namespaced or not. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, now I have faced another problem, I know I'm asking too many questions :D, how can I await the dispatcher so that only after it is done I can proceed to mounting and creating a page?

Comment: The dispatcher would have to return the promise, and then you would await the returned promise from the dispatcher. There's no problem in asking multiple questions. If you need, write another one and ping me in any of these comments, I will gladly take a look (and help whenever I can :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you added the module using key:value, and the key to access your module is *Profile*. Try to call your module using it, or define the module setting directly, without *Profile* key:

```
modules: {
    ProfileData
}
```